# How to fix query inserting twice in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, fullcalendar

[image from phpmyadmin (twice inserted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0bJi.png) My goal is to insert the `<form>` and start date/time and end date/time to the database. After clicking the calendar the start date/time and end date/time will be inserted to the database then a modal will popup(reservation form). After clicking the submit button in the modal the  will now be inserted in the database BUT no start date/time and end date/time. I am using fullcalendar.io

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['title']);
$facility = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['facility']);
$participants = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['participants']);
$start_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['start']);
$end_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['end']);

$query = "INSERT INTO reservation (title, Venue, start_event, end_event, 
Participants) VALUES ('$title', '$facility', '$start_event', 
'$end_event', '$participants')";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    header("location: homepage_client_calendar.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

This is the calendar code

```
if(btn.onclick()){
var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm");
var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm");
$.ajax({
     url:"insert_calendar.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{start:start, end:end},
     success:function()
    {
      calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
      // alert("Added Successfully");
    }
    })
}
```

Comment: simply disable the submit button after first click, or validate db to find the content already existing and then insert if no records found

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj I don't have a submit button after the first click(after clicking the calendar). The submit button that I have is in the `<form>`.

Comment: so before your insert query add a select query SELECT count(*) FROM reservation WHERE title="'.'$title'.'" AND Venue=? AND start_event=? AND end_event=? AND Participants=? if count = 0 and the insert

Comment: Show more code what the data insertion looks like. 
You have many options, using a token, sessions, cookies or even a bad example, i.e. select and check if there is already such a record in the database if not, add a new record or do not add if it already exists.

Comment: If this is a reservation system then of course you must check in your PHP code whether a reservation at that time and facility already exists before you can book it. You need to run some SQL to validate it. Otherwise you are always at risk of duplication

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj the button suggestion doesn't stop someone finding another way of re-submitting the form, or submitting the same data at a later date, or just using a non-browser client to hit the server. The only way to stop someone submitting to the same data is to check the existing reservations in the PHP code before performing the insert (which I think was what you meant by your second suggestion).

Comment: @GrzegorzT. it's a reservation system, so "select and check if there is already such a record in the database" is pretty much the only way to guarantee the record is unique and no duplicate bookings are made for the same time and place. e.g. Not sure how a session value or token would help if someone else makes the same booking?

Comment: " After clicking the calendar the start date/time and end date/time will be inserted to the database then a modal will popup(reservation form). After clicking the submit button in the modal the will now be inserted in the database BUT no start date/time and end date/time." so you are doing this in two stages on purpose, or not? It's unclear. If you want to do it in two stages you need an INSERT followed by an UPDATE. If you want to do it in one stage then you need to stop the calendar from doing an initial insert...but you didn't show the calendar code so we can't help you with that.

Comment: @ASyson You're right, I misunderstood the question.